# How to move object data to be in an index if there is only 1 set of data in the object? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

I am pretty new to JS coding and coding in general, I was hoping for some help. The wording of this question might be wrong as well. I have tried looking for the answer but I'm not sure about the exact wording of the question, so I cannot find the answer, sorry.

The Problem:

I have an object, with a lot of data in it. Each index is an idNumber, inside each idNumber is information on blocked dates for that idNumber as well as other chunks of information specific to that idNumber.

The problem is that if there is only data for 1 block date, the data inside the idNumber is not indexed, and is instead just placed in the object.

Here is a picture of the structure currently:

[image: Current Object Structure]

The top id number of "328029" is correct. The idNumber below "328033" only has 1 block date, and so the information is not indexed in "0".

This is how I want it to look:

[image: How I want the data to look]

My question is how can I push the data inside the idNumber into its own index of "0"?

Sorry again if this is confusing and not written well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and [`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

- Convert the object to an array
- Iterate through each `[key, value]` array pair
- If the `value` sub-object isn't indexed return an indexed version.

**Full code:**

```js
// Rough representation of your data
let data = {
    key1: {
        0: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
        1: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
        2: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
    },
    key2: {
        0: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
        1: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
        2: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
    },
    key3: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
};

let result = 
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => value["0"] ? [key, value] : [key, {0: value}]))

console.log(result)
```

### Regarding your comment:

- We have to use `Object.entries` on both the outer and sub-objects, meaning that this solution is a bit longer and more verbose.
- `keysToKeepOutside` contains a list of keys that shouldn't be moved in your case you should set it to `["UnitInfo", "UnitSeasonInfo"]`.

**Full code:**

```js
let data = {
    key1: {
        0: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
        1: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
        2: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
    },
    key2: {
        0: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
        1: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
        2: { "": 12, "...": 123 },
    },
    key3: { stayOutside: "don't move me", "": 12, "...": 123 },
};

let keysToKeepOutside = ["stayOutside"];

let result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
        if (value["0"]) return [key, value];

        let inside = {}, outside = {};

        for (let key in value) {
            keysToKeepOutside.includes(key)
                ? (outside[key] = value[key])
                : (inside[key] = value[key]);
        }

        return [key, { 0: inside, ...outside }];
    })
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is almost perfect for me, the only issue is that i need the "UnitInfo" and "UnitSeasonInfo" to stay outside of the indexed data. Here is what it looks like with your code: [After your code has ran][1]
Is there a way to do the exact same thing but ignore the "UnitInfo" and "UnitSeasonInfo" index's? Thank you for your help!

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C0v1.png

Comment: @RSGuy Yep got it, I've made an edit to my post with look under the `Regarding your comment` section. Please also note the new array containing the keys that you want to keep outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
const modifyObject = obj =>
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (obj[key].confirmation_id) obj[key] = { 0: obj[key] }
  })

const myObj = {...}

let myModObj = modifyObject(myObj)
```